# How to know if sublime text3 is running code?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text3 but can't figure out how to be aware that the code is actually running (after pressing Cmd+B in a Mac). I have my code and then the small window at the bottom of Sublime that gives me the result of the code. Pretty good when the code runs fast. However, if my code lasts minutes or even hours, I can't figure out if the code is still running or not. The only thing I see at the bottom of Sublime is "Line, Column (bottom left) and UTF-8, Spaces:, Python (bottom right). Any indicator somewhere that the code runs??

In Stata, you have the wheel telling you the code is being run. In R, you know that until you see the ">" in the console, the code is still running. How does Sublime Text indicates that it is actually running code? Btw, I am actually running Python 3.6. code...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: if you want a Python interface for this kind of work, you should probably be looking at Jupyter Notebook

Comment: If Sublime is still actively running a build in the background, the `Tools > Cancel Build` option will be enabled to allow you to stop it; this option is greyed out if Sublime isn't currently building anything.

Comment: Thanks! I was aiming for something more "shiny" :). In the end, I print an ending sentence in my code so that if I don't see it, it means it still runs.